# After clicking AdaptiveAction, how to enable it again

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I have an `AdaptiveSubmitAction` button in an adaptive card, which will also check if users have selected more than 2 options; the bot will reply with a message "Max 2 nos can be selected", this all is working fine.

However, when I am clicking the button after the message comes, it is still disabled i.e. processing sign.  I tried with returning the request with http status ok:

```
new AdaptiveSubmitAction
{
    Title = Constants.SUBMIT,
    Data = dictionary,
};

ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
Activity reply = activity.CreateReply("You can select max 2 nos");
connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivity(reply);

return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
```

---

[image: Attaching image of the button]

Comment: Are you using BotBuilder SDK v3?

Comment: @KyleDelaney Yes

Comment: Disabling the button until a status code is returned is actually a pretty cool feature of Teams. However, it's unclear why your button remains disabled even after returning a status code. Your bot may be doing something unusual, or your Teams app may have an unusual setting. If you don't want to post the rest of your code here then feel free to email me to give me access to your project.

Comment: Yes, but still didn't got any solution yet

Comment: Did you try Wajeed's code?

Comment: Yes, but its behaving the same way

Comment: I work in different time zone, would not be able to give access to you

Comment: Have you tried testing the bot locally with ngrok? https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/19/debug-channel-locally-using-ngrok/

Comment: Ya, have tested the bot locally in teams using ngrok, still its the same, Wajeed was saying it could be a BOT issue

Comment: The point of testing locally with ngrok isn't to see if you still get the issue. The point is to help you diagnose the issue. You could step through your code to see if everything is operating as you expect. But there's very little anyone can do without seeing the rest of your code, as we've never encountered this problem before.

Comment: Do you still need help?

Comment: Yes Kyle, Should i add the code here

Comment: You can share a minimum verifiable example here, sure. Or if you need to share your whole project then you can email me privately.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this sample code snippet? You can put this in [Hello World sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/msteams-samples-hello-world-csharp/blob/master/Microsoft.Teams.Samples.HelloWorld.Web/EchoBot.cs#L11).

```
        if (activity.Value != null) // Handle action.
        {
            Activity replyMessage = activity.CreateReply("You can select max 2 nos");
            await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(replyMessage);
            return;
        }

        AdaptiveCard adaptiveCard = new AdaptiveCard("1.0");
        adaptiveCard.Body.Add(new AdaptiveTextInput()
        {
            Id = "Test",
            Placeholder = "enter your name here",
        });
        adaptiveCard.Actions = new System.Collections.Generic.List<AdaptiveAction>()
        {
            new AdaptiveSubmitAction()
            {
                Id = "testSubmit",
            }
        };

        Attachment attachment = new Attachment
        {
            ContentType = AdaptiveCards.AdaptiveCard.ContentType,
            Content = adaptiveCard
        };

        var reply = activity.CreateReply();
        reply.Attachments.Add(attachment);
        await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
```

Comment: i tried this, but no avail, i am using MessageController to post the message

Comment: Did this code work for you? Could you please share your Bot id which we could try?

Comment: Havent hosted it yet

Comment: You can always use [ngrok to test it locally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/get-started-dotnet-app-studio#tunnel-using-ngrok).

Comment: I am using the same for locally in teams

Comment: Great. Let us know if you still facing issue with the shared code. Please share you Bot Id so that we could check it at our end.

Comment: Bot id- 7451e1f9-e85c-4863-a329-b4f0f21e066a

Comment: I am not getting any response from your bot. Could you please confirm if it is running? What command should I type?

Comment: Could you type "enter time"

Comment: Could you go to enter time and select more than 3 in the drop down box

Comment: Got it. I could repro it with your bot. Could you please try the sample code which I shared once?